# IOS HTML how to know when video is ready to play after onwaiting event

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

Safari does not fire `canplay` after `onwaiting` event (lack of data or `seeked`).

How can I know when the video is ready to play if it's paused so `onplay` and `onplaying` woun`t fire?

I can't see any event that works with Safari in this case

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using? `canplay` is supported in the latest version on both desktop and mobile: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlmediaelement_canplay_event

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan **canplay** fires once when video opens but not after every **onwaiting** like it does on Windows or Android

Comment: On the desktop version of Safari, certain events are not triggered if the file has been served using the file:// protocol. The solution is to serve the file using the http:// protocol or to activate the development tools. I assume this is a security measure, but I'm not sure.